# Show list of all videos from internal storage

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

list all video files from a specific folder from internal storage and display them in flutter.

i want to create an app to list all videos in internal storage and show them in gridview and play that video

Comment: hi , welcome to https://stackoverflow.com . please before ask the question read this guideline. your ask not have reproduce code and you will receive fewer responses. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

To get all the files from the storage you can use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) flutter package. With this, get the folder path, extract all the files with an extension of .mp4 (video file), and store it in List.

```
List<FileSystemEntity> _files = [];

void _getFiles() async {
        Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        List<FileSystemEntity> files = directory.listSync().where((entity) => entity.path.endsWith('.mp4')).toList();
        setState(() {
          _files = files;
        });
      }
```

Then you can use [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) Flutter package to play the video.

```
GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        childAspectRatio: 1,
      ),
      itemCount: _files.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(_files[index])
                ..initialize().then((_) {
                  _controller.play();
                });
            });
          },
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.video_library,
                  size: 50,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Text(_files[index].path.split('/').last),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```